# Tooltip on login page

Tags: users

Does anyone know how I can alter what is displayed in the tooltip shown when hovering over the username and password text on the login screen?

Comment: I don't see any tooltips when I hover over the username or password, but I do when I hover over the Create new account or Request new password links so what theme are you using or do you have any modules installed that would have added this in?

Comment: are you using a contrib module that generate the tooltip? If so chances are that module is adding a description to the form field with hook_form_alter. You could simply do the same https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7